# Change label font color for a line chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart

I'm using Chart.js to generate some charts. The line chart requires labels. I can't seem to figure out a way to change the color of those labels.

```
var chartGood = "rgba(50,182,93,0.5)";
var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["3/14","3/15","3/16","3/17","3/18","3/19","3/20","3/21","3/22","3/23"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : chartGood,
                strokeColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(50,182,93,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [12, 21, 28, 29, 31, 55, 52, 50, 49, 59]
            }
        ]
    }

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("cpu-chart").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
```

I've tried:

```
labelColor : "#fff",

legend : {
    font : {
        color : "#fff"
    }
}

label : {
    font : {
        color : "#fff"
    }
}
```

And a few other combinations but nothing seems to work. I thought I found what I was looking for in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

```
//String - Scale label font colour  
    scaleFontColor : "#fff",
```

but that didn't solve my issue either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the `scaleFontColor` option changes the color of labels.

You probably tried to add it to the data object, that's why it didn't work. Actually it should be passed as a second parameter of the `Line` function like this:

```
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("cpu-chart").getContext("2d"))
    .Line(lineChartData, { scaleFontColor: "#ff0000" });
```

Edit:

Similarly, to change the font size use `scaleFontSize`.

Example:

```
scaleFontSize: 16
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the radar chart type :-(

Comment: @izak They should have some similar property, try to test some of them from documentation. Maybe "pointLabelFontColor" is what you need for Radar charts.

Comment: Indeed, the property I was looking for is pointLabelFontColor. I then had the additional problem that the scale was at the bottom, and if you fill the radar chart with a colour it might completely disappear. To get the scale on top I eventually had to dive into the code and move the drawing of the scale to be last :-)

Comment: Does not work with Chart.js 2.1.3 Line Chart with Time Scales.

Comment: @Mulgard In the updated version I can't find point labels at all, I see points but no text. Maybe they were moved to tooltips? If so, then you can edit titleFontColor of tooltips options.

Comment: What about Chartjs for Angularjs?